# Citation style \citep = "(author (year))"

Tags: citing, natbib

I am currently writing my thesis and I am using `natbib` citation style. When using `\citet` I get exactly the citation style I want "Author (Year)", however when I am using `\citep` the standard result is "(Author, Year)". I know I can modify the brackets, the separator etc. but I would like the results of `\citep` to be "(Author (Year))", see image below. I cannot figure out how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Example]

P.S.: If you want me to I can draw up a MRE but I thought you might be able to answer this without one.

Comment: I'd probably try something like `(\citet{tufano})`, but I think the double parentheses look odd. (I can't really bring myself to recommend overwriting `\citep` with that definition...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try something like this:

```
\renewcommand{\citep}[1]{(\citename{#1}~(\citeyear{#1}))}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this solution but encounter another issue. When I tried to cite multiple authors, like this ´\citep{Tufano,Author2}´, the result would look like (Tufano; Author2 (Year1; Year2)). But I combined your answer with moewe's comment. And will document my solution in a separate answer incase anyone else will have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

After learning from the answers posted I settled for the following solution: `\renewcommand{\citep}[1]{(\citet{#1})}`.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been trying to do this for the past hour, and finally found the solution from another post. You just need to use the command:

```
\setcitestyle{aysep={}}
```

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
   \usepackage{natbib}
   \setcitestyle{aysep={}} 
\begin{document}
   \bibliographystyle{apalike}

   \citep{einstein}

   \bibliography{sample}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add an bib file and add your resulting page in your answer for a fast proof?