# How to redefine \citep command such that it returns author-year style citation for multiple authors?

Tags: biblatex, citing, multiple-citations

I need the in-text  citation style to be author-year, i.e: "Author1, 1999". I have implemented

```
\renewcommand{\citep}[1]{(\citeauthor{#1},~\citeyear{#1})}
```

(from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515358/citation-style-citep-author-year)) which returns what I want if there's only one author. But if there's multiple authors it returns:

```
(Author1, Author2, 1999, 1998)
```

What I need is:

```
(Author1, 1999, Author2, 1998)
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the citation command, you should set the citation style. As far as I can deduce from the example, in your case this would be:

`\setcitestyle{authoryear,comma,aysep{,}}`

The first option indicates you will use author year, the second option that the separation between citations needs to be a comma, and the final option that the separation between author and year needs to be a comma.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!! How can I encolse the citation in parantheses though?

Comment: The command \citep means you place the citation in parentheses. The alternative is \citet where you place the citation in the running text. In author-year style, this means only the year will be placed in parentheses. Note that both are natbib commands. If you wish to use biblatex as your tag implies, you are better off using \parencite and \textcite. See the answer of @moewe for more on that.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `biblatex` as the tagging suggests, use an `authoryear` style, set `nameyeardelim` and `\multicitedelim` and cite with `\autocite`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareDelimFormat[parencite]{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman}
dolor \autocite{nussbaum}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde, 1998, Worman, 2002) dolor (Nussbaum, 1978)]

It is almost always a bad idea to combine several `\...cite` commands into a single `\newcommand`, because commands thus defined cannot deal with multiple citations, need additional help to handle pre- and postnotes and can confuse the various citation tracking features.